# Node Express upload file with additional data

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to Node JS want to create Rest API for Upload Image and facing this issue.

I want to create a post method with multiple files and additional data from inputs. This is my code:

**index.js :**

```
app.post('/upload-photos', upload.array('photos'), function (req, res) {
  const uploadInfo = req.files.map(file => {
    return {
      sourceName: file.originalname,
      newName: file.filename
    };
  });
  res.send(uploadInfo);
});
```

My issue is I want to add some form data like (name, address, phone), has anyone else experienced this, please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `multer` additional fields can be accessed through `req.body`.

```
app.post('/upload-photos', upload.array('photos'), function (req, res) {
  const { name, address, phone } = req.body;

  const uploadInfo = req.files.map(file => {
    return {
      sourceName: file.originalname,
      newName: file.filename
    };
  });
  res.send(uploadInfo);
});
```

In your form:

```
<form action="/upload-photos" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="photos" multiple />
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <input type="text" name="address" />
  <input type="text" name="phone" />
</form>
```